# Simulations - Placing Balls in Holes in Random

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, probability

In this simulation that is planned to conduct there are 100 balls in the 100 holes. Let's say that balls are randomly thrown in the holes 1000 times. I want to calculate the relative frequency of empty holes in the sense that for 1000 times, what is the frequency of 1 hole is empty; 2 holes are empty; 3 holes are empty,..., to 99 holes are empty. I tried using **combination** functions and **Monte Carlo Simulations** but I could not find a reliable way to stimulate this experiment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension of the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/588069/214015) answer on Cross Validated for the exact solution involving Stirling numbers of the second kind, including an `Rcpp` function that uses a brute-force approach. The number of empty holes is simply `n - k`.

Here is a function to estimate the probability of observing `k` non-empty holes using Monte Carlo simulation:

```
couponssim <- function(n, m, nrep) {
  tabulate(
    replicate(
      nrep,
      length(unique(sample(n, m, TRUE)))
    ),
    n
  )/nrep
}
```

Compare the set of probabilities using the three functions:

```
n <- 100L # number of holes
m <- 100L # number of balls

k1 <- coupons1(n, m) # exact formula with approximate Stirling numbers
k2 <- coupons2(n, m) # exact probabilities through brute-force calculation
ksim <- couponssim(n, m, 1e5L) # 100K Monte Carlo replications
    
plot(1:100, k1, xlab = "k", ylab = "p(k)", col = "blue")
points(1:100, k2, col = "orange", pch = 20)
points(1:100, ksim, col = "black", pch = 3)
legend(0, 0.12, legend = c("p(k1)", "p(k2)", "p(ksim)"), pch = c(1, 20, 3), col = c("blue", "orange", "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: When you say coupons1 and coupons2 in the second part of the coding that you posted, what do you mean? You did not define anything about them.

Comment: Follow the link to the answer on Cross Validated. I'll re-post it here for convenience: 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/588069/214015